# Default attribute is nil for Chef Apache2 cookbook

Tags: apache, chef-infra, cookbook

I'm trying to provision an Ubuntu 13.04 box with Chef-solo (11.4.4), however the apache2 cookbook gives an error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

 20:  package "apache2" do
 21>>   package_name node['apache']['package']
 22:  end
```

My guess is that the default attributes for the cookbook are not loaded, i.e. node['apache'] is nil, but I have no clue how to solve this...

```
case platform  
when "debian", "ubuntu"
   default['apache']['package'] = "apache2"
```

I know there have been some changes to Chef v11 regarding attributes and previously with Chef v10 it simply works, but I don't have enough Chef knowledge to know what to change.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, in Chef 11, cookbooks need a `metadata.rb` in which dependencies are specified. These dependencies are used to autoload cookbooks.

Adding `depends "apache2"` to the `metadata.rb` file solves the above problem.